# Certification for Plutus Smart Contracts

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program

What does the process look like for certification and auditing of Plutus Smart Contracts?  What are required steps to prepare your dApp for certification?

Answer (score 1):

Too soon to say. The only public announcement so far is https://iohk.io/en/blog/posts/2021/09/22/bringing-certified-dapps-to-cardano